# En android studio obtengo el siguiente Error: No debugable applications

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy teneniendo el siguiente mensaje en Android Studio 1.5.1:

> Error: No debugable applications

Intento reiniciarlo y sigue sin funcionar. Pero antes sí funcionaba y no se ha instalado ningún plugin ni librería ni se han efectuctuado cambios en el SO. Ver imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despues de indagar sin obtener ninguna solucion, ni cerrando/reiniciando el ide funcionaba lo que me parecia extraño pues al pricipio si que funcionaba sin ningun problema pero de repente, despues de hacer varias pruebas ver abajo funciono:

solucion que encontre respuesta rapida:

cerrar el `ide` cuando se vuelva a iniciar activamos:

`Tools` >> `Android` >> `Enable ADB Integration`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero importante antes de cerra el ide cerrar tambien el

```
Android Device Monitor (ADM)
```

(pues en mi caso este era el que hacia que se produciera 
el error tiene que estar cerrado antes de iniciar el ide)

---

"Creo el problema empieza al lanzar una aplicacion y despues abrir el ADM con esta abierta, se puede observar que `ADB integacion se desactiva` (en mi caso)"

**Soluciones varias y pruebas:**

- Si despues de obtener el error miras para activar el ADB sin cerrar
  el ADM y lanzas la `app run` apareceran erros de este tipo la mayoria
  de la veces.

  ```
  Tubería rota
  java.io.IOException: Tubería rota
  ```
- Si cierras el `ADM`, lo vuelves a abrir y haces `app run` algunas
  veces salen errores del tipo:

  ```
   Tubería rota
   java.io.IOException: Tubería rota
  ```
- Si cierras el `ADM` y haces `app run` **sin lanzar el ADM**, y despues cierras la app en la X. Ahora activas el `ADM` y lanzas la app **si funciona** (revisar que este activo el ADB integracion).

Notas: abrir el `ADM` con la app sin estar activa, (para evitar que se desactive la integracion con `ADB`).

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: esto trabajo para mi, android studio 1.5.1 Saludos

Comment: ¿Encerio dice `Tuberia rota`? ¿no dice `broken pipe`?

Comment: jaja mira que mientras hacia las pruebas me llamo la atencion pero espera que lo mire haber, es que tengo que forzar el error un momento

Comment: si sale Tuberia rota, a mi tambien me sorprendio, pero como estaba liado con el error despues se me paso eso, y el ide esta en ingles osea la interface esta en ingles, java.io.IOException: Tubería rota, pues ahora me sale la duda haber si todos los errores mes los va a decir en español jaja Saludos

Comment: @jasilva se me olvido la arroba

Comment: que interesante situacion, va a fav, por si algun dia encuentro algo asi

Comment: Prueba la Preview 2.0 de Android Studio versión Estable, te sorprenderá la velocidad del Instant Run, eso si lo debes activar si importas proyecto en settings.